# Using updateMany with $pull for array in document leads to MongoError 11000 duplicate key error for unique index

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have been trying to figure out, why I get the following error:

> MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: db_test.contentcomments index: comments.guid_1 dup key: { comments.guid: null }

when doing this:

```
ContentComment.updateMany(
    {},
    {
      $pull: { comments: { userId: userIdToDelete } }
    })
```

The model `ContentComment`:

```
const Comment = new Schema({
  guid: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  userId: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: false,
    index: true
  },
  comment: String,
  timestamp: {
    type: Date,
    default: new Date()
  }
});

const ContentComment = new Schema({
  contentGuid: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    index: true
  },
  comments: [Comment],
  counter: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  }
});
```

Looking at the collection in Robo3T, I see that there are four indexes:

```
{
    "_id" : 1
}
```

```
{
    "contentGuid" : 1
}
```

```
{
    "comments.guid" : 1
}
```

and

```
{
    "comments.userId" : 1
}
```

For contentGuid and guid, the "unique" field is checked.

An example document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1c86ba03ca187cb10456e3"),
    "contentGuid" : "295582c2-a710-40ee-893a-907921dd6fcd",
    "__v" : 0,
    "comments" : [ 
        {
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2020-01-13T15:03:25.266Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e1c86bd97adbe23d00a7cs0"),
            "userId" : "f8da5e7d-8e92-4a3c-9765-f69af8bs1s81",
            "comment" : "Test",
            "guid" : "e700c572-85b7-42fc-8c9d-4d43esd322de"
        }
    ],
    "counter" : 1
}
```

I am not trying to insert any documents, as you can see. I have tried to use `update` with `multi: true` instead but got the same error. I have also tried to get all documents using `find({})` and then iterating through the documents with `forEach`, using `$set` to give it a "hand-filtered" new comments array, but I always get the same error.

Also, I am pretty sure the syntax should be fine, because I have run it on a different collection successfully! And I have checked all guids - none of them are the same.

Does anyone see something I'm doing wrong or know how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please list out your indexes on this collection, and please provide document examples.

Answer (score 0):

I dropped the index on guid (through robo3t) and now it works. I noticed that in the model, guid does not have a flag for index: true. I am not sure, why there was an index in the mongo database at all.. Maybe someone can comment on that.

Comment: You probably had it previously and then removed. To ensure only indexes explicitly defined in model, use this method : https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.syncIndexes